# How to use non thread safe libraries in multi threaded programe

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

While I'm reading a article about thread safeness. I got this sentence.

*"Be careful if your application uses libraries or other objects that don't explicitly guarantee thread-safeness. When in doubt, assume that they are not thread-safe until proven otherwise. This can be done by "serializing" the calls to the uncertain routine, etc.*"

So my question is what is `serializing` here. As example If I have non thread safe library that need to use in multithread application. How to do that?

Comment: lock before make library function call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serializing means making it so that only one thread can be executing a call to the library at any given time.  For example, if you are using a pthreads mutex, instead of just calling:

```
SomePotentiallyNonThreadSafeLibraryFunction();
```

you would call:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&_myMutex);
SomePotentiallyNonThreadSafeLibraryFunction();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_myMutex);
```

That way if a second thread tried to execute the above code while the first one was in the middle of a call to SomePotentiallyNonThreadSafeLibraryFunction(), the second thread would wait (inside the pthread_mutex_lock() call) until the first thread's call had returned and unlocked the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, `serializing` means that you use some kind of locking behaviour to avoid allowing concurrent calls to the same, non-thread-safe, code.

For instance, you can define a "critical section" around your non-thread-safe code. Access to that critical section would only be allowed to 1 thread at the same time, using some kind of locking mechanism.

For instance, you can use a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex) to avoid concurrent access. There are other primitives that also help you control shared access to commong resources.